# Someone reads to me vs someone reads for me

Tags: meaning, prepositions

what is the difference in the meaning between the following two sentences:

> Someone reads to me.
>
> Someone reads for me.

I think first sentence means someone reads something aloud for me or someone reads something so that I listen to him/ someone reads something and the destination of listening to him is me, And the second sentence means someone reads something for my sake. Am I on the right track ?

Comment: You are right.  _For_ is slso used in the sense "on behalf of".

Comment: @Khan 'To' here indicates the destination of someone  to listen him/her, that's 'me' in the example: "someone reads to me."  Am i correct?

Answer (score 7):

I’d say you’re on the right track. The first phrase – *reads **to** me* – is very common for read-aloud situations.

> Every day in fourth grade, our teacher read to us.

The second wording – *reads **for** me* – is less idiomatic and subject to interpretation. I’d interpret it to mean reading something so that you don’t have to. It’s an uncommon situation, but I can think of a few places one might say that. For example:

> I couldn’t understand all that legalese in the contract, so I had my lawyer read it for me.

The presumption would be that the lawyer would discuss any parts of the contract that might prevent me from signing it.

Comment: J.R what do you mean by **I’d interpret it to mean reading something so that you don’t have to**. Here, you haven't used 'don't have to+ **verb**

Comment: @J.R. my first thought was of public readings - e.g. during church services. As in: It was my turn to do the reading, but I had to go out of town, so John read for me.

Comment: @yubrajsharma They've left off part of the sentence that is implied. "...reading something so that you don't have to read it." This is very common in English. We know that they're talking about "you" not needing to do something and that something is the reading they were talking about.

Comment: Nathan k Ok, now I've understood "so that you don't have to read' 'Read' is left out as it's implied.